# Please am trying to start my react app with 'npm start' is not running

Tags: reactjs, terminal

Please below is the message am getting from powershell. Please am a beginner in react how can i fix this problem.

process ID (PID): 14132

Command line: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe '-noexit' '-command' 'try { . "c:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\browser\media\shellIntegration.ps1" } catch {}'

Shell integration failed to activate

The following extensions have contributed to this terminal's environment:

Git

i went ahead to click on the 'show environmental contribution'

this is what is displayed on vs code

## Terminal Environment Changes

### Extension: vscode.git

- `GIT_ASKPASS=c:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\askpass.sh`
- `VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE=C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe`
- `VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS=--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node`
- `VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN=c:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\askpass-main.js`
- `VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE=\\.\pipe\vscode-git-e8a5386475-sock`

I have tried the below instruction i saw in github but is not working and i also uninstalled VS code and installed back yet still not working

Ensure you have the latest version of PowerShell installed. Download it from [here](https://aka.ms/powershell-release?tag=stable) if needed.

In VS Code, go to "Settings" (click on the gear icon or use Ctrl+,) and search for "terminal.integrated.shell".

Update the "Terminal > Integrated > Shell: Windows" setting to the path of the newly installed PowerShell executable (e.g., C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe).

Save the settings and restart VS Code.

If the issue persists, try disabling all extensions temporarily to check if any extension is causing the problem. You can do this from the "Extensions" view (click on the square icon or use Ctrl+Shift+X). Restart VS Code and see if the issue is resolved. If it is, re-enable the extensions one by one to identify the problematic one.